# my javascript function that deletes the last index doesn't work for else statement

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have a button that it deletes the last index of this.fullformula properly which is a string
but for the this.result it won't work which is an integer it will just delete one character and not looping over the function
I think it is something wrong with this.formula in else statement that is new so I added this but still not working

it's a calculater project we have fullformula , result and currentinput currentinput will get each charactor you're typing before operators fullformula is the phrase includes numbers operators result is the answer of fullformula
actually I'm new to import vue in code snippet and it would be great if someone tells me how to do it especialy when you have components
my project is on this repository github.com/rozhansh43/vue-cal

```js
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data {
      currentSign: '  ',
      currentInput: '  ',
      fullFormula: '  ',
      result: '',
      inputResult: '  '
  },
  methods: {
    updateNumber (digit) {        
      if (digit === '.') {
        if (!this.currentInput || !(this.currentInput * 1)) { 
          this.fullFormula = '0'
        }
        if (!(this.currentInput.includes('.'))) {
          this.fullFormula += '.'
        }
      } else {
        (!this.currentInput || (!(this.currentInput*1) && !(this.currentInput.includes('.')))) ? (
            this.currentInput += digit,
            this.fullFormula += digit
        ):(
            this.currentInput += digit,
            this.fullFormula += digit
        );
      }
    },
    changeSign () {
      this.currentSign ? this.currentSign = '  ' : this.currentSign = '-'
    },
    addOperator (op) {
      if(this.result) {
        this.fullFormula = `${this.result} ${op} `
        this.result = '  '
      } else {
        if (this.currentInput) {
          this.fullFormula += `${this.result} ${op} `
          this.currentSign = '  '
          this.currentInput = ''
        } else {
          if (this.fullFormula.includes(' ')) {
            var temp = this.fullFormula.split('')
            temp[temp.length-2] = op
            this.fullFormula = temp.join('')
          }
        }
      }
      
    },
    execute () {
      if(this.fullFormula) {
        this.fullFormula
        this.result = eval(this.fullFormula)
      } else {
        this.fullFormula
        this.result = this.currentInput
      }
      
      this.currentSign = '  '
      this.currentInput = '  '
      
      this.fullFormula = this.result 
    },
    clear () {
      this.currentSign = '  '
      this.currentInput = '  '
      this.fullFormula = ''
      this.result = ''
    },
    lastindex () {
      if (this.result == '') {
        this.fullFormula = this.fullFormula.slice (0,-1)      
      } else {
        this.fullFormula = this.result.toString().slice(0, -1)
        this.result = this.fullFormula.Number(this.fullFormula)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: 0.25s ease;
}

.abs-center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.block {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.rela-inline {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.flex-r {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-c {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.flex {
    flex: 1 1 0;
}

body {
    transition: 0s;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.small {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.calculator {
    width: 420px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.display {
    margin: 10px 5px;
    background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    font-size: 36px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.display *::before {
    content: "";
    background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}

.button {
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 5px;
    max-width: 90px;
    background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
    box-shadow: 4px 3px 80px 3px rgb(201, 201, 201);
    border-radius: 3px;
    flex: 1 1 0;
}

.button:hover,
.button:active {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button.wide {
    flex: 2 1 0;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.button.wider {
    flex: 3 1 0;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.button.grey {
    background-color: rgba(53, 55, 59, 0.5);
}

.button.grey:hover,
.button.grey:active {
    background-color: #494d5a;
}

.button.hidden {
    cursor: default;
    opacity: 0;
}

.button.disabled {
    cursor: default;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.button.disabled:hover,
.button.disabled:active {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 94px;
    background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
    box-shadow: 4px 3px 80px 3px rgb(201, 201, 201);
    border: none;
    padding: 0 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="abs-center calculator">
    <input  type="text" v-model="fullFormula" @keyup.enter="execute"/>
    
    <div class="block button-section">
      <div class="flex-r button-row">
        <div class="button grey" @click="clear">
          AC
        </div>

        <div class="button grey" @click="lastindex">
          C
        </div>

        <div class="button" @click="changeSign">
          +/-
        </div>
        
        <div class="button" @click="addOperator('/')">/</div>
      </div>

      <div class="flex-r button-row">
        <div class="button" @click="updateNumber('7')">
          7
        </div>

        <div class="button" @click="updateNumber('8')">
          8
        </div>

        <div class="button" @click="updateNumber('9')">
          9
        </div>

        <div class="button" @click="addOperator('*')">
          *
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flex-r button-row">
        <div class="button" @click="updateNumber('4')">
          4
        </div>

        <div class="button" @click="updateNumber('5')">
          5
        </div>

        <div class="button" @click="updateNumber('6')">
          6
        </div>

        <div class="button" @click="addOperator('-')">
          -
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flex-r button-row">
        <div class="button" @click="updateNumber('1')">
          1
        </div>

        <div class="button" @click="updateNumber('2')">
          2
        </div>

        <div class="button" @click="updateNumber('3')">
          3
        </div>

        <div class="button" @click="addOperator('+')">
          +
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flex-r button-row">
        <div class="button wide" @click="updateNumber('0')">
          0
        </div>

        <div class="button" @click="updateNumber('.')">
          .
        </div>

        <div class="button grey" @click="execute">
          =
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is `this.result`? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Really impossible for us to know what is going on with the information provided. I also have no clue what "it will just delete one character and not looping over the function" means

Comment: Strings do not have a method named `Number()`, so unless you have code that adds one, `this.fullFormat.Number()` will throw a Syntax error. Please [edit] your question to provide values for `this.result` and `this.fullFormula` at the time of running. Please also provide the errors you are seeing into the console. There is no loop in the code presented.

Comment: To convert a string to a number, you write `Number(this.fullFormula)`

Comment: it's a calculater project we have fullformula , result and currentinput currentinput will get each charactor you're typing before operators fullformula is the phrase includes numbers operators result is the answer of fullformula could you please take a look at my repository github.com/rozhansh43/vue-cal  @Unmitigated

Comment: @epascarello it's a calculater project we have fullformula , result and currentinput currentinput will get each charactor you're typing before operators fullformula is the phrase includes numbers operators result is the answer of fullformula could you please take a look at my repository github.com/rozhansh43/vue-cal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked like this

```
lastindex () {
  if (this.result == '') {
    this.fullFormula = this.fullFormula.slice (0,-1)      
  } else {
    this.result = this.result.toString().slice(0, -1)
    this.fullFormula = this.result
  }
}
```